# Pandas groupby value and get value of max date and min date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` looking like this :

```
item year value
A    2010  20
A    2011  25
A    2012  32
B    2016  20
B    2019  40
B    2018  50
```

My goal is to be able, for each item to calculate the difference of value between each date. Then for example, I want to find for item A : 12 (32 -20 because year max is 2012 and year min is 2010) and for item B : 20 (40 - 20, because year max is 2019 and year min is 2016).

I use the following code to get, for each item, year max and year min :

```
df.groupby("item").agg({'year':[np.min, np.max]})
```

Then, I find the year min and year max for each item. However, I stuck to make what I want.

Comment: Ah. The difference between the values corresponding to the maximal and minimal year. That was a bit unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sort_values` by `year`, then you can `groupby` and select `first` for `min` and `last` for `max`:

```
g = df.sort_values('year').groupby('item')
out = g['value'].last() - g['value'].first()
```

Output:

```
item
A    12
B    20
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
def fun(x):
    return x[x.index.max()] - x[x.index.min()]


res = df.set_index("year").groupby("item").agg(fun)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
      value
item       
A        12
B        20
```

Answer (score 0):

Use loc accessor in agg to calculate value difference and also, you can also concat the first and last year in an item to give you a clear indication of the range.

```
df.sort_values(by=['item','year']).groupby('item').agg( year=('year', lambda x: str(x.iloc[0]) +'-'+str(x.iloc[-1])),value=('value', lambda x: x.iloc[-1]-x.iloc[0]))



      year    value
item                  
A     2010-2012     12
B     2016-2019     20
```